# Running multiple commands from multiple terminal windows from python script

Tags: python, shell, unix, terminal

I have a problem where I need to write a python script, which basically opens one terminal windows and starts a node js server in it, then opens another terminal windows and starts a java program in it.

If I run two subprocess.call() functions they operate in the same terminal window.

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks.:)

Answer (score 3):

Use subprocess.Popen:

This will create new window for each bot and run program in it. The -i option for python3 is to make the window interactive after the TestBot3.py script finishes.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

bot1 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "TestBot1.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
bot2 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "TestBot2.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
bot3 = Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "-i", "TestBot3.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

Or you can use `from subprocess import call`

```
call(["python3", "TestBot1.py"])
call(["python3", "TestBot2.py"])
call(["python3", "TestBot3.py"])
```

To open a terminal for each you can use gnome-terminal with -e Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal:

```
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 TestBot1.py"])
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 TestBot2.py"])
call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 TestBot3.py"])
```

Comment: So if I want to use the Popen option and those two commands I want to execute are for example "cd Desktop && npm start" and "cd Desktop/folder && mvn exec:exec" , how do I achieve this? I am not very experienced in this manner so it is not that clear to me :) thanks

Comment: you can  specify path of program file like "TestBot1.py" with you directory "Desktop/test/TestBot1.py".