# Running multiple python scripts with subprocess python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run multiple python scripts in parallel with `subprocess` in a linux OS

Similar to this: [Running multiple commands from multiple terminal windows from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520553/running-multiple-commands-from-multiple-terminal-windows-from-python-script)

Here is what I tried:

```
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 ab.py"])
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 bc.py"])
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3 cd.py"])
```

Unfortunately, the terminal flashes in split seconds and disappears. Any reason for this? adding `shell=True` makes the terminal stays but does not execute the script.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]? Note that [subprocess.call waits for completion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), so it's a) not suitable for your task and b) an indication that the failure is in *what* you execute not *how* you execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.run` should work:

```
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3", "ab.py"], shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3", "bc.py"], shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3", "cd.py"], shell=True)
```

**Edit:**

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -x python ab.py")
```

Comment: It does this same. what could be the issue?

Comment: it doesnt. it shows the shell and then the script did not run. I dont know whats wrong

Comment: I tried with the shell=True. The terminal stays but does not run the python script. Any thoughts around this?

Comment: @JA-pythonista I edited with 4 elements in a list, did you see that edit?

Comment: Yes, I did. It opens the terminal and does nothing

Comment: @JA-pythonista Edited my answer how about now

Comment: I have tried this before, it opens the terminals and does nothing

Comment: maybe I try Popen? Tried that too

Comment: same issue, opens a new terminal and does nothing

Comment: the same issue, unfortunately. opens a new terminal and does nothing

Comment: @JA-pythonista How about if you change `ab.py` to the full path

Comment: it runs with just python ab.py but I want it to open in a new terminal

Comment: @JA-pythonista Check my **Edit:** part

Comment: They all worked. I just realised the terminals get closed immediately they're ran and that happened really fast. Thanks so much for your help. Well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to split all parts of the command line into separate strings?

```py
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python3", "ab.py"])
```